# Extract two variables from multiple netcdf files to plot

Tags: r, netcdf, argo

I am using [this example](https://github.com/ArgoCanada/argoFloats) and trying to build on it.

```
library(argoFloats)
library(oce)
## 1. Get worldwide float-profile index, saving to ~/data/argo by default.
indexAll <- getIndex()

## 2. Narrow to a 30km-radius circle centred on Abaco Island, The Bahamas.
index <- subset(indexAll,
            circle=list(longitude=-77.06,latitude=26.54,radius=30))
#> Kept 41 cycles (0.00153%)

## 3. Get NetCDF files for these profiles, saving to ~/data/argo by default.
profiles  <- getProfiles(index)

## 4. Read the NetCDF files.
argos <- readProfiles(profiles)

## 5. Examine QC flags, and set questionable data to NA.
argosClean <- applyQC(argos)
oldpar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))                     # want two-panel plot
par(mar=c(3.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0))         # maps do not get axis names
par(mgp=c(2,0.7,0))                    # tighten axes

## 6. Plot a map of profile locations.
plot(index, which="map", bathymetry=FALSE)
points(-77.06, 26.54, pch="*", cex=3)  # show centre of focus
mtext(paste(argosClean[["length"]], "profiles"), line=1.0)

 ## 7. Plot a TS diagram
par(mar=c(3.5, 3.5, 2.0, 1.0))         # increase left margin for name
plot(argosClean, which="TS")
```

When you download the data for the Bahamas region, there are multiple netcdf files. I am trying to download all the .nc files, then make a single plot of pressure vs. temperature but with each .nc file being a different colour. unfortunately I only get one profile that is plotting. how do I get all the profiles to plot?

```
library(ncdf4)
con <-  list.files("/Users/data/argo/",pattern='*.nc',full.names=TRUE)
con <- lapply(con [1:40],nc_open) #only use the first 40 and not all 41 files

print(con)
lon <- ncvar_get(con, "LONGITUDE")
lat <- ncvar_get(con, "LATITUDE")
press <- ncvar_get(con, "PRES")
temp <- ncvar_get(con, "TEMP")

as.df <- cbind(lon, lat, as.numeric(press), temp, name)

plot(press~temp, ylim = rev(range(press)), xaxt="n",  data=as.df)
axis(3)
```